# My machine is 32 bit, but i have 64 bit processor. Should I install 64 bit ubuntu?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, cpu

I was interested in what machine do i have so after

```
sudo lshw
```

I've got info, but there is one thing that puzzles me.
It writhes that my laptop is 32 width, but for cpu that it is 64 width

```
description: Notebook
product: HP G7000 Notebook PC (KQ192EA#ABU)
vendor: Hewlett-Packard
version: F.35
serial: xxxxxxxxx
width: 32 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.4 dmi-2.4 smp-1.4 smp
.
.
.
-cpu
      description: CPU
      product: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU          540  @ 1.86GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: e
      bus info: cpu@0
      version: 6.6.1
      serial: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
      slot: CPU
      size: 1866MHz
      capacity: 1866MHz
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 533MHz
      capabilities: boot fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss tm pbe nx x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm dtherm
```

So should i try to switch to 64 bit Ubuntu or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notebook has 1GB RAM according to Google, not enough RAM to install a 64-bit operating system. Because of the limited amount of RAM Ubuntu will lag on this laptop. If you want to improve your laptop's performance, you have a choice of installing either Xubuntu 32-bit, which is comparable to Windows Vista in look and feel or Lubuntu 32-bit, which is comparable to Windows XP. In either case you should choose the 14.04 release, because the 14.04 releases of Xubuntu and Lubuntu have long term support for security and maintenance updates until April, 2017.

On the other hand, if your laptop has 2GB RAM, I recommend staying with Ubuntu 32-bit.

Comment: The confusion seems to be that although the OP's processor is 64bit, the motherboard is only 32bit.

Comment: I've added more RAM so now i have 3GB.
Can i add more RAM and then run 64 bit Ubuntu or this confusion that @RohithMadhavan pointed to makes a problem?

Comment: Your motherboard doesn't support 64-bit operating systems, however Ubuntu 14.04 and later has [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) enabled by default, which supports up to 64GB of RAM for 32-bit operating systems. PAE is a feature to allow 32-bit CPUs to access a physical address space (including RAM and memory mapped devices) larger than 4GB. This is just for the CPU, the motherboard may have a different maximum limit for the amount of RAM that it can support.

Answer (score 0):

You can run 32 bit or 64 bit Ubuntu if you have a 64 bit system,  but I suggest installing 32 bit if your notebook only has 1GB of RAM (according to karel). 64 bit Ubuntu would lag if you don't have enough RAM. I would recommend 64 bit if you have 4 or more GB of RAM.

Hope this helps!